# xText Variable/Attribute Assignment

Tags: variable-assignment, xtext

I built a grammar in xText to recognize formal expressions of a specific format
and to use the generated object tree in Java.
This is what it looks like:

```
grammar eu.gemtec.device.espa.texpr.Texpr with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate texpr "http://www.gemtec.eu/device/espa/texpr/Texpr"

Model:
    (expressions+=AbstractExpression)*  
;

AbstractExpression:
    MatcherExpression | Assignment;

MatcherExpression:
    TerminalMatcher ({Operation.left=current} operator='or' right= MatcherExpression)?
;

TerminalMatcher returns MatcherExpression:
    '(' MatcherExpression ')' | {MatcherLiteral} value=Literal
;

Literal:
    CharMatcher | ExactMatcher
;

CharMatcher:
    type=('text'|'number'|'symbol'|'whitespace') ('(' cardinality=Cardinality ')')?
;

/* Kardinalitäten für CharMatcher*/
Cardinality:
    CardinalityMin | CardinalityMinMax | CardinalityMax| CardinalityExact
;
CardinalityMin:         min=INT '->';
CardinalityMinMax:      min=INT '->' max=INT;
CardinalityMax:                 '->' max=INT;
CardinalityExact:       exact=INT;

ExactMatcher:
    (ignoreCase='ignoreCase''(' expected=STRING ')') | expected=STRING
;

/* Variablenzuweisung 
 * 
 * z.B. $myVar=number
 * */
Assignment:
    '$' name=ID '=' expression=MatcherExpression
;
```

Everything works fine except for the 'cardinality' assignment.

The Expressions look like this:
text number(3)    -    (an arbitrary amount of letters followed by exactly 3 numbers)
symbol number(2->)  -    (an arbitrary amount of special characters followed by at least 2 numbers)
whitespace number(->4)  -    (an arbitrary amount of whitespaces followed by a maximum of 4 numbers)
number(3->6)    -    (at least 3 numbers but not more than 6)

When I run Eclipse with this grammar (so that my language is recognized and has code completion and so on), everything I type is shown in the "Outline"-tab as a tree-structure as it should, except for the cardinality values.
When I add a cardinality statement to a CharMatcher, the little plus appears before it, but when I click on it it just disappears.

Can anyone tell me why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, I think the problem was that the compiler could not decide which class to create at this point:

```
Cardinality:
CardinalityMin | CardinalityMinMax | CardinalityMax| CardinalityExact
;

CardinalityMin:         min=INT '->';
CardinalityMinMax:      min=INT '->' max=INT;
CardinalityMax:                 '->' max=INT;
CardinalityExact:       exact=INT;
```

So I simplified the whole thing a little, it now looks like this:

```
Cardinality:
    CardinalityMinMax | CardinalityExact
;

CardinalityMinMax:  (min=INT '..' max=INT) | (min=INT '..') | ('..' max=INT);
CardinalityExact:   exact=INT;
```

It is still not shown in the "Outline"-Tab, but I suppose that is a problem of the visualisation.
The generated classes now work as intended.

Comment: Yes, I had have the same problem and applied the same solution.